Can I still install an undermount sink if the quartz cutout is as big as the cabinet width?
I’m looking to replace my drop in sink with an undermount and was told it was doable in general. However I looked under the sink and it looks like the width of the cutout runs against the edge of the cabinet. Can I still install an undermount?
Photos of the bottom of sink with quartz cutout: https://imgur.com/a/1WnQ6v6

No.  The opening is too big.  The width isn't the biggest problem. Even if you replaced or modified the cabinet, the opening is too close to the back wall and it has been cut crudely with uneven rough edges and corners.  To undermount you need a new top.
Also your undermount sink will have to be a lot smaller which presumably is a problem, hence why it was done this way.
